# Inconsistent letter rendering on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webfonts

I purchased a webfont called 'Forza' from typography.com, they provide a stylesheet which I can include on my page in order to use it, like so :

`<link href="https://cloud.typography.com/7051852/795664/css/fonts.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">`

On Chrome it looks completely fine, Firefox on the other hand doesn't render some characters correctly and falls back on the browser default (times new roman).

**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox]

**Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

Comment: This might be because Chrome uses Webkit and Firefox uses Gecko.... Might.

Comment: What format is the font?

Comment: When viewing this font in Firefox on their website it looks fine to me. http://www.typography.com/fonts/forza/characters/

Comment: @MathewFoscarini That might be because the site does not actually use the font, but inline `<svg>` to display preview characters. OP Ask typography.com support about it.

Comment: @nmaier ah okay, thanks. OP try different font weights.

Comment: @nmaier Yeah did, I'm about to check my inbox for a response, thanks

Comment: @MathewFoscarini did try different weights, same thing though. I'm going to check out your links, thanks.